# A 3 digit number is produced by randomly by rearranging the digits 1,2,3. the person receives this in money. find the expected value received?

Tags: probability

The prize for winning a lottery is as follows. A three digit number is produced by randomly rearranging the digits 1,2,3 and the winner is to receive an amount in money obtained (eg. 321). find the expected value of the amount the person will receive??

here is the long version.

I am stumped?

help needed

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i,j,k}P(X=i,Y=j,Z=k)(100i+10j+k)$$
Where $i,j,k$ is choosen to be some permutation of ${1,2,3}$

The number of permutations of ${1,2,3}$ is $3!$ then assuming equal probabilities you have $P(X=i,Y=j,Z=k)=\frac{1}{6}$. So:

$$\sum_{i,j,k}P(X=i,Y=j,Z=k)(100i+10j+k)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i,j,k}(100i+10j+k)$$

Then you have $123+132+213+231+321+312=1332$

$$\sum_{i,j,k}P(X=i,Y=j,Z=k)(100i+10j+k)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i,j,k}(100i+10j+k)=\frac{1332}{6}=222$$

Other way of seeing it is any number will appear two times in the position of 100, two in the position of 10, and two in the position of the unit. $$100\cdot 2 \cdot (1+2+3)+10\cdot 2 \cdot (1+2+3)+1 \cdot 2 \cdot (1+2+3)=222 \cdot 6 =1332 $$

If you have $n$ digits then the problem is:
$$\sum_{i_0,...,i_n}P(X_0=i_0,X_2=i_2,...,X_n=i_n)(10^0i_0+...+10^ni_n)$$
The number of possible permutations if $n!$ and each digit would appear $(n-1)!$ times en each position (because when you fix one then you have $(n-1)!$ permutations possible) then:
$$\sum_{i_0,...,i_n}(10^0i_0+...+10^ni_n)=1\cdot (n-1)! \cdot (1+2+3+...+n) +...+ 10^n \cdot (n-1)! \cdot (1+2+3+...+n)=(1+10+..+10^n)\cdot (n-1)! \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}  $$

Then:

$$\sum_{i_0,...,i_n}P(X_0=i_0,X_2=i_2,...,X_n=i_n)(10^0i_0+...+10^ni_n)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{10^{n+1}-1}{10-1}\cdot (n-1)! \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Simplifying:

$$\sum_{i_0,...,i_n}P(X_0=i_0,X_2=i_2,...,X_n=i_n)(10^0i_0+...+10^ni_n)=\frac{10^{n+1}-1}{10-1}\frac{(n+1)}{2}$$

Which for $n=3$ would result in $222$, I did the test for $n=4$ and match with the formula ($2777.125$)

Answer (score 0):

So there are two components to this question: (1) find the probability that you would get any one of the outcomes described, and (2) the expected value of the outcome (that is, the average amount any one individual would make if an infinite amount of people played this game and you averaged their results).

So to tackle (1), you need to find the probability of selecting one of those digit combinations. If you can only use the digits 1, 2 and 3 without replacement, that means in the first place you can place any of the 3 digits, in the second place 2 and in the third place 1. In other words, $ 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 3! = 6$ different ways. So the probability of selecting any one of the combinations of digits is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Now to step (2): we need to weight all the outcomes by the amount we expect to receive. We can get this amount by summing all the values. That is 
$$ $123 + $132 + $231 + $213 + $312 + $321 = $1332$$

So the expected value is the result of (1) times the result in (2) and we get $$ \frac{$1332}{6} = $222 $$

So we would expect the average person to get somewhere around $222.